# Object Required in Array, Creating an array with all of the last rows used in a workbook file

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, object, runtime-error

I'm having some issues with arrays in vba. I was able to create one array, I would then like to pass values of this array into another array but creating this second array is proving to be difficult as I am getting a Run Time 424 Error, Object Required.

**The goal is to have all of the last rows used in the sheets of my excel file stored in this array. Here is my code so far.**

````
Sub Combinetables()

 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
 Application.EnableEvents = False

'Setting up Worksheet (tabs)
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim wsInputsList As Worksheet: Set wsInputsList = wb.Sheets("InputsTab")

'InputTabs sheet names
Dim shtName As String

' Row counters
Dim lastrowInputs As Long, i As Long, nshts As Long

lastrowInputs = wsInputsList.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ReDim ws(1 To lastrowInputs) As Worksheet 'dim your array only once

'Assigning Sheet Names
For i = 1 To lastrowInputs
shtName = wsInputsList.Cells(i, 2).Value ' store current "possible" sheet name
Set ws(i) = wb.Sheets(shtName) ' update sheets array
Next

'Assigning Last Row Numbers
ReDim lastrowsTab(1 To lastrowInputs) As Range
For k = 1 To lastrowInputs
Set lastrowsTab(k) = ws(k).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Next


End Sub```
````

Comment: `.Row` returns the row *number*, not the `Range`.

Comment: so how could I correct this loop?

Comment: Do you want the last row numbers, or the `Range` objects? The comment is `'Assigning Last Row Numbers` so it's a little unclear.

Comment: I want the value of the row count stored in the array. For example if sheet 1 or "ws(1)" uses 6 rows in column 1, I would like to have lastrowsTab(1) = 6

Comment: Then `lastRowsTab` should not be declared `As Range`, but `As Long`... and drop the `Set` too.